# Get Method Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin.forms, xaml

He creado un servicio *API REST* en *.NET*. Estoy creando una aplicación en *Xamarin Forms*. Cuando trato de consumir el servicio en forma de lista, me genera errores. Les muestro el código y agradezco mucho a quien me pueda ayudar.

Esta es mi conexión con el servicio:

```
public Alamacenes getAlmacenes()
        {
            try
            {
                Alamacenes almacenes;
                var URLWebAPI = "https://www.avila.somee.com/ApiAlexa/api/Almacenes";
                using (var Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
                {
                    var JSON = Client.GetStringAsync(URLWebAPI);
                    almacenes = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Alamacenes>(JSON.Result);
                }

                return almacenes;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Desde aquí lo llamo:

```
protected async void OnAppearing()
        {
            Repositorio repo = new Repositorio();
            Alamacenes listalmacenes = repo.getAlmacenes();
            foreach (var item in listalmacenes.CodigoAlmacen.ToString())
            {
                base.OnAppearing();
                Almacen.Items.Add(item.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Esta es la clase:

```
public class Alamacenes
    {
        public int CodigoEmpresa { get; set; }
        public string CodigoAlmacen { get; set; }
        public string GrupoAlmacen { get; set; }
        public string Responsable { get; set; }
        public string Almacen { get; set; }
        public string Domicilio { get; set; }
        public string CodigoPostal { get; set; }
        public string CodigoMunicipio { get; set; }
        public string Municipio { get; set; }
        public string CodigoProvincia { get; set; }
        public string Provincia { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }
        public int AgruparMovimientos { get; set; }
        public string IdDelegacion { get; set; }
        public string IdAlmacen { get; set; }
    }
```

Cuando trato de usar el `method` no recibo ningún tipo de respuesta.

Comment: Por favor, traduce tu pregunta, estás en StackOverflow en Español. Sino, terminará cerrada.

Comment: ya lo hice gracias @Superg280

Comment: Tu clase se llama "A**la**macenes" y estas recibiendo objetos "Almacen**e**" revisa a ver si es eso

Comment: donde no recibis respuesta? en el httpclient o cuando serializas?

Comment: Seguro que recibis un json, porque consulte tu api y me lo formatea como xml

Answer (score 0):

Fijate que en tu metodo parece estar recibiendo un listado de almacenes, y no un solo almacen por lo menos eso sugiere el nombre de tu metodo.

**
**//Edito mi respuesta porque llame a tu url y envia un array en lugar de List**
**

```
public Alamacenes[] getAlmacenes()
    {
        try
        {
            Alamacenes almacenes;
            var URLWebAPI = "https://www.avila.somee.com/ApiAlexa/api/Almacenes";
            using (var Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
            {
                var JSON = Client.GetStringAsync(URLWebAPI);
                var listado = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Alamacenes[]>(JSON.Result);
            }

            return listado;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

protected async void OnAppearing()
    {
        Repositorio repo = new Repositorio();
        Alamacenes[] listalmacenes = repo.getAlmacenes();

        base.OnAppearing();

    }
```